# Automate troubleshooting on networks

Tags: python, linux, bash, ansible, expect

I want to develop a tool to automate troubleshooting on networks. Today I use a shell script that I created, it uses *bash* and *expect* but the problem is that I can only work with the data at the end of the script.

Current functions: the *bash* script requests some information for the user (user, password, IP, MAC), after this the *bash* script starts an *expect* script that enters on the equipment of my network, runs a list of predetermined commands and the output is recorded in a variable of the *bash* script, after the finishing of the *expect* script the *bash* script acts on the data parser.

I would like to do something more "smart", that enter on a device and that each command can be treated individually, without the need to run all possible commands, go back to the command line, perform the parser and depending on the output to do everything again

I need something 'agent less' and I'm using Linux. What programming language / framework can I use? Could you give me any ideas and tips? (I do not need a GUI, just the command line is perfect)

I use SSH to enter in the devices (in some cases I need to enter in a jump server using SSH and inside it use a script to enter the equipment). command example:

> show ip bgp summary
>
> ping xxx.yyy.zzz.www
>
> show ports X
>
> show vlan X

and several others

If I have not left something clear, please let me know and thank you in advance.

Comment: take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For common cases, you should try Ansible- look through the [network documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/#network).

For more specialized cases, I highly recommend [Netmiko](https://github.com/ktbyers/netmiko). It's a Python library that provides an expect-like interface and handles a lot of network ssh quirks.

To make the commands run through a jump box, you can look into ssh config options to forward commands. Then your script's commands will automatically proxy through your jump box. Sorry, I dont remember the exact options, and it can be a pain to find the magic combination.

You should also consider joining the [Network To Code Slack community](http://networktocode.herokuapp.com/). It's a great place to ask quick questions and a good mix of beginners to experts.

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for answering,

Helped me a lot, now I have a direction.

Regards,

Comment: @erton I was doing a lot of this until recently, so your question made me think of my early days with it. Some more tips: ansible/netmiko have their share of bugs, so be sure to use them with python virtual environments (venvs). Definitely worth taking the time to learn about venvs. Follow the links on the netmiko repo and the news channel on networktocode. New tools are coming out constantly and they might do just what you want.